# Using signed URL (generated on server) in Fineuploader

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Is there a way where we can use a signed URL (generated on server) in Fineuploader for file upload instead of just the signed policy (we want to this so that we can use Using IAM Roles to Delegate Permissions to Applications that Run on Amazon EC2(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/roles-usingrole-ec2instance.html))

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fine Uploader S3, then you must sign the requests server-side. If you would like support for signed URLs, please [open up a feature request in the project's issue tracker](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/new), so we can discuss further. We would have to explore the exact workflow along with specific changes required in the library to support this workflow.